# multiple push providers with parse.com

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a product with an home made push provider. We try to add parse.com as a provider.

No problem with ios (os manage push, everything work with unity plugin).

But I'm very confused with android, I've tried many different things but I never had push from parse and our push with the same configuration. I integrate parse android plugin 1.8.3, add all datas in the manifest, modified Application class to init Parse, everything works well. Installation datas are sent to parse. I can send a push with dashboard, I have "This will be sent to 1 devices" but after sending it status is succeeded "0 pushes sent". No error, nothing append on device.

Where can I find why I target 1 device and why 0 push are sent ? Is it really possible to have 2 differents services which manage com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE and com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION ?

manifest push parts :

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="bundleId" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- GCM homemade notifications -->
<service android:name="com.homemade.unityApp.notifications.UnityGCMReceiverService" />
<receiver android:name="com.homemade.unityApp.notifications.UnityGCMCustomBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="bundleId" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to have two push on the same app

you must setup on manifest the `permission` and `users-permission` as described on the official guide https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

and have two `receive` on the manifest with the appropriate `intent-filter`
**both SDK must register the push**. An example is the app I work on, we have:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
String regid = gcm.register(GCMID);
```

and

```
Localytics.registerPush(GCMID);
```

one from our own server and one from localytics push. I believe parse.com will have it's on `registerPush` method.

On those case both `BroadcastReceiver` will receive the message, so it's kind of necessary to put a token in the push message to filter which of them should ignore the message and which should act on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that the 2 registration are ok, I changed by hand some datas in Parse database and I received push from both, now I have to find how to do this without changing data with my little hand, Parse ask us to add a meta, but I suspect that this meta is ignored.

Comment: On my app we're adding on the bundle that the receiver receives "fromLocalytics":" true" and just check for it on Runtime

Comment: Hi Budius: I'm also trying to integrate Localytics on Android but I'm facing an issue. Can you please take a look at this question (thanks!) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072845/localytics-push-notifcations-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I've added several times  without any success. 
I've tried to add senderId in java code when sending installation datas and it work. I really don't know why just add meta didn't work, maybe I've missed something.

So the original manifest is ok, parsegcmbroadcaster seems to correctly filtering notifications.